# replace the strings with variables in python

Tags: python

The following statement works as expected and myreservation object is created.

```
myreservation = conn.run_instances(amiid, placement='us-east-1a', key_name='n15a',instance_type=my_instance_type,security_groups=['N-1-0-1-AutogenByAWSMP-'])
```

But the following does not work. I get an error in the script later because myreservation object is not created.

```
 myreservation = ("conn.run_instances('%s', placement='us-east-1a', key_name='n15a',instance_type='%s',security_groups=['%s'])" % (amiid, my_instance_type, my_security_groups))
```

I need to replace the security group with variable because that will make it easy for me to change it later.

error is:

```
The security group '%s' does not exist
```

when I print that statement and run it at python console, it works as expected

And the following does not work either:

```
 myreservation = conn.run_instances('%s', placement='us-east-1a', key_name='nov15a',instance_type='%s',security_groups=['%s']) % (amiid, my_instance_type, my_security_groups)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second version doesn't work because you put "conn.run_instances" into the string which probably is not what you want. hard to tell from your very small code example  but I'd guess:

```
myreservation = conn.run_instances(amiid, placement='us-east-1a', key_name='n15a',instance_type=my_instance_type,security_groups=[my_security_groups])
```

is what you are looking for (assuming `my_security_groups` is correctly set)

edit:

> Why does %s does not work?

'%s' works fine if you use it correctly.

in your third example:

```
 myreservation = conn.run_instances('%s', placement='us-east-1a', key_name='nov15a',instance_type='%s',security_groups=['%s']) % (amiid, my_instance_type, my_security_groups)
```

you try to use a single replacement tuple for three different strings. this does not work, you'd have to replace each string individually. something like this would probably work, but it doesn't really make sense to use string replacements if you're replacing the whole string

```
myreservation = conn.run_instances('%s'%amiid, placement='us-east-1a', key_name='nov15a',instance_type='%s'%my_instance_type,security_groups=['%s'my_security_groups])
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. As if I care, is it pythonic way? Why does %s does not work?

Comment: I guess the single replacement tuple works for three different strings in print statement. But not otherwise.

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing "replace `%s` in three different strings" with "replace three occurences of `%s` in a single string"...? ;-)